# Too many function calls from mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with my simple js code. For unknown for me reason it call function to many times. In perfect if hoover with my mouse over div it should call function 1 time. Instead if calls function each time I move mouse over something in my div.
Here my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4" data-lat="50.12" data-lng="19.10" data-name="pierwszy element" id="oferty">
     <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
     <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
     <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Here my Js code:

```
$("#oferty.col-md-4")
     .mouseover(function () {
        //$(this).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
        modifyPoint($(this).attr("data-name"))      
 });
```

I suppose that there is something wrong with my selectors. Can anyone tell me how to modify it?

Comment: mouseover is trigger even when a child element is 'hovered' use mouseenter instead `:p` .. a workaround would be to use a flag to be set to true while hovering the first time and then setting it to false on mouseout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) from child elements will get propagated to the parent element

```
$("#oferty.col-md-4").mouseenter(function () {
    //$(this).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    modifyPoint($(this).attr("data-name"))
})
```

[MDN: mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter)

> Similar to mouseover, it differs in that it doesn't bubble and that it
>   isn't sent when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants'
>   physical space to its own physical space.

Comment: `mouseenter` event doesn't propagate?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is 'mouseenter', not 'mouseover' ;-)